# How does multi-level ORM work in cakephp?

Tags: php, cakephp, orm

I have the following structure:

- Order ---- (hasMany) ----> Carton, Shoe
- Carton --- (belongsTo) --> Order
- Carton --- (hasMany) ----> Shoe
- Shoe ----- (belongsTo) --> Order, Carton

So  Order --> Carton --> Shoe

When saving data to the database Order is fine, Carton is fine, but Shoe only gets the "carton_id" set correctly, "the order_id" is null. Is there any way to make this work?

Also when I want to list all the shoes belonging to a particular order (without using order_id) How can I find all shoes which belong to a carton which belongs to a specific order?

Comment: I could use $this->Order->find('all', array('recursive' => 3));
But I want to use SQL group, to give me only the distinct shoes, because I have a lot of duplicates, and I just need one distinct, and a count field.

I need something like: $this->Delivery->Shoe->find('all', array('group' => 'fieldname')); But I need to specify the Delivery ID somewhere...

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Or what have you found when looking for an answer?  (the reason I ask, is, I believe this is pretty clearly explained many many places online including the CakePHP book).  If you've tried what they suggest, and it STILL doesn't work, then provide that code, and we can help further.